# primal to dual conversion problem

Tags: linear-programming

primal problem is:
$$\min z = 4x_1-3x_2+5x_3$$

$$7x_1+6x_2+24x_3\le16$$

$$2x_1+5z_2+3x_3\le10$$

$$x_i\ge0$$
the optimal solution is: $(0,2,0), z = -6$

The dual problem is :
$$ \max g = 16w_1+10w_2$$

$$7w_1+2w_2\le4$$

$$6w_1+5w_2\le-3$$

$$24w_1+3w_2\le5$$

$$w_1,w_2\le0$$
I get the optimal solution $g=0$ which is wrong because of the duality theorem, $z(opt)=g(opt)$.
What's wrong with it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear program you give as the dual is correct. However, the optimal solution isn't $g=0$, but rather $g=-6$ at $(w_1,w_2)=\left(0,-\frac{3}{5}\right)$.

Notice that $g=0$ isn't a possibility because if $g=0$ then we have $w_1=w_2=0$ which then does not satisfy the constraint 
$$6w_1+5w_2\le-3$$
You can also notice that this is the only nontrivial constraint in the dual program - the other constraints are satisfied merely by the $w_1,w_2\le 0$ requirement.

Comment: Hi thanks. How do you solve the problem, I tried the II phase method adding an artificial variable to try to get a starting basic  feasible solution, but it failed because no basic variable outgoing I've found, but i think I've done some computation errors.

Comment: @blob Sorry, I actually know quite little about linear programming - I solved this question with basic calculus which was easy to do because I only had one nontrivial constraint to deal with. If you want to know about a particular method I might suggest asking another question.

Comment: I'm wrong with the simplex method because the variable space is $(-infinity,0)$, so the basic feasible solution must be negative.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

MIN zx  =           x1  +   2   x2
subject to
-   2   x1  -   4   x2  ≥   -160
x1  -       x2  =   30
x1              ≥   10
and x1,x2≥0;

Since 2nd constraint in the primal is equality, the corresponding dual variable y2 will be unrestricted in sign.

Dual is (Solution stpes of Dual by BigM method)

MAX zy  =   -   160 y1  +   30  y2  +   10  y3
subject to
-   2   y1  +       y2  +       y3  ≤   1
-   4   y1  -       y2              ≤   2
and y1,y3≥0;y2 unrestricted in sign

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).